# Trouble filtering on paramteter in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, builder

I am having trouble filtering my table on a parameter and keep getting the error:
"The FilterValue expression for the dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a colon or a line terminator.  Colons and line terminators are not valid in expressions."

Filter is...
Expression : Month      Date/Time
Operator : >
Value: =IIF(Parameters!City.Value = "Dallas", 8/1/2018, 10/1/2018)

When I put just a date in the 'Value' box the query works fine. It is when I try to link to parameter I start getting issues.

Comment: Try putting the dates in double quotes like `"8/1/2018"`.

Comment: Try putting the dates in number signs like #8/1/2018#.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap a `CDate()` around it. Also check if your report language is set to a value.

```
'Expression with a Date/Time Filter
=IIF(Parameters!City.Value = "Dallas", CDate("8/1/2018"), CDate("10/1/2018")
```